# Photoshop action issue with word file

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a coupon design (PSD) and a word file (DOCX) each line in this file has a serial number, I want to copy and paste each line to a specific area in that design. Then save as this design (JPG). I want to repeat this operation until all serials are finished.

[image]

the data inside my word file like this:

111111
222222
333333
444444

**Edit**
*This what I tried:*

First i converted my word file to PDF to be able open it on photoshop, then i made an action to take a copy from selection area in this PDF file and paste it the specific area in my coupon. My problem is to move this selection to the next line in PDF file and repeat this operation until all serials finished. Someone can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post from Photoshop Help about data-driven graphics might be able to help you set up your data file and PSD in a way that's a little better for what you're trying to do:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html

The general steps they outline (in much more detail) are:

- **Create the base graphic to use as the template.** Use layers to separate the elements that you want to change in the graphic.
- **Define variables in the graphic.** Variables specify the parts of the image that change.
- **Create or import the data sets.** You can create the data sets in the template, or import them from a text file.
- **Preview the document with each data set.** To see how your final graphics will look, you can preview before you export all the files.
- **Generate your graphics by exporting them with the data.** You can export them as Photoshop (PSD) files.